# optimal RX beamforming

Tags: digital-communications, beamforming

I was asked this question in an interview couple of weeks ago. I think I answered it correctly, but I think I might missing some points. Here is the problem, following by my answer.

**Part 1)**

In Figure 1, for one of the TX beam, we have two of the strongest RX beams, $V_1$, $V_2$, obtain frequency-flat complex channel estimation of $h_1$ and $h_2$. Other RX beams receive no signal.

- What is the optimal RX beam for best performance?

[image]

Figure 1

---

**Part 2)**

[image]

Figure 2

Now let's assume for one of the TX beam, two of orthogonal strongest RX beams, $V_1$, $V_2$, obtain two channel responses of $\mathbf{h}_1$ and $\mathbf{h}_2$, respectively. Other RX beams receive no signal. Channel response has $K$ taps and can be written as
$\mathbf{h}_1 = (h_1[0],h_1[1]\dots,h_1[K-1])$ and $\mathbf{h}_2 = (h_2[0],h_2[1]\dots,h_2[K-1])$

- What is the optimal RX beam for best performance?

**Answer**:
For both parts, we do Maximum Ratio Combining to get he optimal RX beamform for the best performance (here maximizing the received SNR), assuming $h_1$ and $h_2$ are obtained. One can write the SNR as $SNR = \frac{|w^H * x|^2}{(w^H * N)}$ where after maximizing this term, we can see MRC is the solution.

However, I think there could be more to this problems. Can this be done using any other beamforming methods to get the best performance (based on maximizing SNR)?